# Applying for Credit Card Under New EIN

Tags: credit-card, credit-score, ein

I have established a new EIN for a sole proprietorship under my name. This business' purpose is to separate my ventures flipping and doing other projects that make money from my personal finances. I have an email with a custom domain and a website for my business. I have a Google Voice phone number. I want to apply for a business credit card to register accounts and manage expenses - specifically the Chase Ink Business Unlimited card. According to Nerdwallet, this card requires a credit score of at least 690. I have not established any credit history on this EIN. Will I likely get accepted for this card if I apply? If not, what should I do to be accepted?

Comment: They will look at your personal credit history so if it is good you will get a card.  I have that card for a small business and the approval process was quick.

Comment: I don't have my SSN associated with my EIN.

Comment: @GShocked: Your application to Chase will list both EIN for the cardholder, and SSN for the personal guarantor.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all business credit cards are granted by assessing the credit worthiness of the business owner(s) and the business. So they'd require your SSN to assess your individual credit score and ability to pay.

Not sure if this is still the case, but Office Depot and Shell gas cards were ones you could get with only EIN when I checked a while back.

Corporate credit cards can be EIN-only, but they typically have a host of requirements that likely don't suit your small business and you'd still have to prove that your business has the ability to pay. In the case of your LLC that could mean providing personal tax returns. From my experience with real-estate loans, lenders wanted 2-years of business history before factoring in my business income.

If you need credit now, you're likely stuck with including SSN, if you just want to build your business credit and work towards eventually having a business line of credit with no personal guarantee then you should look at pre-paid/secured business credit cards.

Comment: The number I've seen is that corporate cards require at least $4 Million of annual revenue.